# Parsing a string to remove or escape special characters

Tags: android, kotlin

```
Android Studio 3.1
Kotlin 1.2.31
```

I have the following string resource that has the following text and special characters at the end "Provides extra %1$s"

For different languages the `%1$s` will not be present.

I am trying to create a method to try and see if it will be present. However, getting a false as I am thinking `$` is a special character.

Is there a way to ignore the special characters I have tried to escape using the '/' but didn't work. as the method will always return false even though the special charactors are present.

```
private fun containsExtra: Boolean {
    val extra = "%1$/s"

    return resources.getString(R.string.extra).endsWith(extra)
}
```

Many thanks for any suggestions,

Comment: The usual character used for quoting special chartacters is '\', not '/'. I think endsWith(extra) should work with your example if you remove the '/'. But I wouldn't rely on this always being at the end, in all languages.

Comment: Your expect result is `true` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to change`val extra = "%1$/s"`  to `val extra = "%1\$s"`